# How to acess Linux bash terminal with new Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, terminal-emulator

A few months ago Microsoft announced a [new open source terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=nOD%2FrLJHOac&ranSiteID=nOD_rLJHOac-dY2xslLnl4wLs8q1E5Cblw&epi=nOD_rLJHOac-dY2xslLnl4wLs8q1E5Cblw&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=%28ir__wnh0o6onhokfrlabkk0sohzixv2xj1zfk63mrug300%29%287593%29%281243925%29%28nOD_rLJHOac-dY2xslLnl4wLs8q1E5Cblw%29%28%29&irclickid=_wnh0o6onhokfrlabkk0sohzixv2xj1zfk63mrug300&activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) they are working on:

As you can see in the [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gw0rXPMMPE) of the video you can access an Ubuntu/Debian etc bash terminal from the Windows terminal.

My question is how do you access this? Do you have to enable the Linux sub-system for Windows and then download the distro form the Windows store? If so something I'd also like to ask is what are the downsides of enabling such a thing? Does it close down your boot time? Does it risk borking your computer etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the windows subsystem for linux WSL. I use it very often. You need windows 10 >= 1709 (winver). Acitvate the wsl windows feature, download a linux version from the store and run the bash command. I don't have any problems yet.

Comment: Thank you, one question before I mark as correct, can you elaborate on "run the bash command"?

Comment: you are welcome. start the windows commandline and then type the command `bash`. it is only one way of many others, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-guide-to-invoking-wsl/

Answer (score 1):

If you install versions of WSL they appear in your Start menu and you can click the icon to open a Bash console directly, without installing the New Windows Console, and also without opening a cmd.exe console window and typing "bash" or "wsl". If you install New Windows Terminal, you can open, from a menu, a console tab for Powershell and cmd.exe, as well as any WSL versions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 terminal exe is usually instled on:

> C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe

As a regular Ubuntu terminal, that has their own "subsystem" but you can also access to other Windows path.

Has their own user and their own configuration on .bashrc